# Undefined control sequence in a NOWEB document (\nwstartdeflinemarkup)

Tags: noweb

In a document NOWEB compiled with the following command

```
noweave -tex -filter "elide comment:*" adocument.nw > documentation.tex
```

and trying to compile the resulting file with the command

```
xetex -halt-on-error documentation.tex
```

I got the following error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on}\endmoddef \nwstartdeflinemarkup 
                                              \nwenddeflinemarkup
```

It seems that \nwstartdeflinemarkup is not recognized.

If I delete from the document all the sequences

```
\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
```

the document compile normally.

What can be the problem?

Comment: It is generally better to allow a question to be migrated than to delete [your old question on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162790/undefined-control-sequence-in-a-noweb-document) and create a duplicate on another site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is an error in the distribution of noweb, where a few commands that I think should be present in both the support for TeX and for LaTeX is actually only available for LaTeX.

A simple fix is to add the two lines to the start of the source file:

```
\let\nwstartdeflinemarkup\relax
\let\nwenddeflinemarkup\relax
```

Some background information on this. Given this source file:

```
One line of documentation.  
<<SomeChunkname>>=  
// No real code  
@ %  
Second and last line of documentation.
```

and running `noweave` and then `xelatex`:

```
noweave -tex adocument.nw > documentation.tex
xetex -halt-on-error documentation.tex
```

replicate the error, hardly surprising because `\nwstartdeflinemarkup` is not defined in `nwmac.tex`. Now, browsing a source file for `nwmac.tex`, namely `support.nw` in a [ctan mirror site](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/web/noweb/src/tex) reveals that `\nwstartdeflinemarkup` is defined for LaTeX, but not for TeX.